# How can I throw a type error in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typeerror

I’m stuck with the following Typescript problem:

> *Write a function that decides whether a user is logged in. Sometimes, it's called with a number of times that the user is logged in. Other times, it's called with true. It's never called with false*

My code so far:

```js
function isLoggedIn(param: number | boolean ) {
  if (param === 0) {
    return false
  } else if (param === false) {   
    return false
  } else {
    return true
  }
}
```

I can’t figure out how to handle the case when the function is called with false, so that a type error could be returned.  If I do:
 `if (param === false) {return false}` , I get back an error

> *Expected: type error but got: false*

If I throw the TypeError myself, i.e. `if (arg === false) throw new TypeError('type error')`
I get back an error "*Expected: type error but got: TypeError: 'type error'*

Does anyone know how to make the function work?

Comment: I would guess that they actually want you to have `param: number | true`. However, I do agree that the text is misleading, as "type error" does indeed make me think of TypeError.

Comment: @VLAZ, it doesn't work, unfortunately

Comment: Provide your assertion expectation code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that the `Type error` referred in the question, is not a JS `TypeError` but a TypeScript type error at compile time, so something like:

> Argument of type 'false' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number | true'.(2345)

You can change your declaration to be:

```
function isLoggedIn(param: number | true) {
  if (param === 0) {
    return false
  } else {
    return true
  }
}
```

See `number | true`. Here `true` is meant to represent the *literal* "true" value, not just a boolean, so that you can pass "true" but not "false".

You should adapt the `if` condition inside too, since param will never be `false`, as posted in the example. So you can use it like:

```
isLoggedIn(10); // ok
isLoggedIn(true); // ok
isLoggedIn(false); // TS Error
```

You can check it here: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=31&pln=9&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgGTgc0wUwCYCSYAFAA4CGATuQLYBciYINARjpYgD6JSUg4BKRAG8AUImTBEZKrUQBeRYgAMQsRImUcUEJSTByAGxQ5xiAL6IcxnCLObtupL35nzo96NQZs+IsQBGVQBuRAB6MMQ4AGsvdCxcQhIXQVCIqNjvBL8SAxsBNMiAFQBlRABRSko4SiA)

Comment: I got it. it worked. thank you so much.have been struggling for almost a day with this.